# Modifying Running Code in Xcode Fix (found in the 'Run' menu)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am attempting to use the 'Fix' command found in the 'Run' menu in Xcode to modify my running code without having to rebuild. I have read apple's documentation on it but following their 
'typical fix-and-continue workflow:' (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/230-Modifying_Running_Code/modifying_running_code.html) doesn't seem to be working for me...

Here is what i am doing (from scratch):
 - create view-based project in Xcode
 - create click event to trigger a function that just logs some output
 - run in simulator with debugger (command-Y)
 - click 'pause' in the debugger.
 - add another log (or some other simple change) to the function 
 - save modified code
 - select 'Fix' from the 'Run' menu
 - click continue and click button

The added log doesn't appear...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, per se, but this "Fix and continue" system is disappearing in XCode 4. I wouldn't invest a lot of time in learning to use it, or developing a debugging strategy around it.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Any suggestions of other ways to see modify running code without rebuilding?

Comment: Not that I know in the sense I suspect you mean. You can always use a more dynamic language which can rewrite itself at runtime (or under your instruction, with a suitable debugger). For C and C derivatives, the best I know of for a general solution is dynamically loaded library code (and so dynamically replaceable library code).