# XCode debuging on simulator after code is changed

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

is there any way to update simulator after application code is changed without restart the application on simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you just have to stop the app in the simulator and run it again.

Comment: I spent a while looking to see whatever happened to Xcode 3's "Fix & Continue" feature.  [It appears to be *gone* as of Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156995/modifying-running-code-in-xcode-fix-found-in-the-run-menu).